# Is there an equivalent of node/express' app.locals in rails?

Tags: web-services, ruby-on-rails-4, express

Once set, the value of [app.locals](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals) **properties persist throughout the life of the application**.

Is there a way this can be achieved with rails?

Comment: application.rb does the same thing, but can you be more specific ?

Answer (score 0):

Check those great gems, they are exactly what you need:

https://github.com/railsconfig/config

https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro